# How to define name for s3bucket for different environment in Kafka Sink

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am currently setting up my aws s3 bucket for different environments so I can have data in dev, tqa, stg, and prd. The name of my bucket in dev is s3.dev.kafka.sink while in tqa it is named as s3.tqa.kafka.sink each associated with its correct env. The documentation in the Kafka Connect website doesn't specify how to be set the environments, so I did the following way, however I keep getting errors that the bucket name is not named properly.

I put it in the secret yaml file

```
apiVersion: kubernetes-client.io/v1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
   name: kafka-sink-s3-secret
   namespace: namespace
spec:
   backendType: secretManager
   data:
       -key: s3.tqa.kafka.sink
        name: bucket_name
        property: bucket_name
```

While in deployment file

```
env:
   -name: bucket_name
    valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
         name:kaka-sink-s3-secret
         key: bucket_name
```

And I will specify the bucket name in the config:
`"s3.bucket.name":"'"$bucket_name"'"`

But it fails to deploy. Any idea how can i specify as `s3.{{ENV}}.kafka.sink` so it runs the correct bucket name in their own env in aws

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Kafka Connect doesn't have any way to access environment variables other than those defined by the AWS SDK (the keys and profile, at least)

Sounds like you will need to use a ConfigProvider of the Kafka Connect API

Here's one example on Github, which you'd need to compile and load into your Docker images - https://github.com/giogt/kafka-env-config-provider

Inside the connector properties, use like this

```
"bucket.name": "${env:ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME}"
```

You should be able to use Helm to better separate/template out the full bucket name within the secret/deployment resource definition

Comment: I tried to -name: bucket_name and value: s3.-{{ENV}}-kafka.sink' and when I deployed I got s3.-tqa-.kafka.sink, but i don't want the -tqa-, I just want .tqa. how to exclude the -

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem, but if you don't want dashes, don't put them in the string